# Ruby: How to create a custom iteration method for a Enumerator Object - with enum_for?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Lets say, we have an `Array` of `Strings` named `words` and I want to instantiate a special Enumerator using `eunum_for` on it which only counts Strings with the length != 3. Here is my proposal:

```
def words.n_each
  select{|x| x.length != 3}.each do |y|
    yield y
  end
end

e4 = words.enum_for(:n_each)
e4.each do |w|
  puts w
end
```

But there has to be a more smarter rubyish way to include the mechanics of the `n_each` method in `enum_for` - maybe inside a codeblock at the time of instantiation of the Enumerator. But how?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear as to your desired outcome or usage.

Comment: based on my example, I am looking for `e4 = words.enum_for(:select, {|x| x.length != 3}` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Is `lazy` what you are looking for?

```
p e4 = ["aaa","c","foo","aaaa"].lazy.reject{|s| s.size == 3 } # => <Enumerator::Lazy: ["aaa", "c", "foo", "aaaa"]>:reject>

e4.each do |w|
  puts w
end
```

prints

```
c
aaaa
```

Comment: No I wasn't looking for lazy, but I was looking for this Syntax! You saved my evening. This is the way: e4 = words.enum_for.select{|x| x.length != 3} . Amazingly I have not found this syntax in any doc. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric what do you mean not documented ([`Kernel#to_enum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-mruby/Kernel.html#method-i-to_enum) `words.enum_for` creates an `each` enumerator and then `select` returns an `Array` this would be identical to removing the `enum_for` in this case.

Comment: @engineersmnky: that's very clear, but in the case of `each.meth` the enumerator knows already what's to do. `meth` works on the return value of `each` (an enumerator). But in `enum_for.meth` `meth` is kind of an argument needed to create the enumerator. That's a little bit weird in my eyes.

Comment: I just figured out, that `enum_for.meth` does **not** create the custom enumerator. It behaves just like `each.meth`. That means, the syntax is consistent - but I am still looking for a possibility to create a custom enumerator with `enum_for`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def each_except_size_3
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      (0..size-1).each do |i|
        s = self[i]
        y << s unless s.size == 3
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
enum = ['guppy', 'owl', 'ox', 'cow', 'bear', 'lion'].each_except_size_3
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007fc1a41b9a28>:each>
```

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["guppy", "ox", "bear", "lion"]
```

```
enum.take(4)
  #=> ["guppy", "ox", "bear", "lion"]
```

```
enum.take(3)
  #=> ["guppy", "ox", "bear"]
```

```
enum.take(99)
  #=> ["guppy", "ox", "bear", "lion"]
```

```
enum.next
  #=> "guppy"
enum.next
  #=> "ox"
enum.next
  #=> "bear"
enum.next
  #=> "lion"
enum.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Comment: That's clear - my question aimed at the `enum_for` method.